# $ajax success response print HTML page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this code in my JS function, I need to call a PHP file "valiadte-attrib-form.php" this PHP script returns a variable. 
This is my HTML page:

```
 <form method="post" id="form1" name="form1" action="<?php echo $editFormAction; ?>">

<script>
   $(function() {   
     $('#form1').submit(function() {
        return validateForm();
     });
   });
</script>
```

This is my JS code:

```
 function validateForm() {
    var form = $("#form1");
    $.ajax({
        context: form,
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'validate-attrib-form.php',
        data: params,
        success: function(response){  
            alert(response);
            result=response;  
            return result;
        }.bind(form)
    });
```

This is my PHP code:

```
    <?php  
     echo "false";
```

But my problem is when a I see **alert(response);** I see full HTML codelike this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="es">
<head>  
   <meta charset="iso-8859-1"/> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
.....
.....
```

What's wrong in my code? I need that **alert(response)** shows **false** not HTML code.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like you are hitting a 404 or other error page that you are redirected to via your PHP code. Try hitting the php file in the browser and see what you gets printed on screen.

Comment: What's the content of your `$editFormAction` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting a server error like a 400 or 500-series error ... Sometimes, depending on how the server is configured, this may look like a re-direct, at which point you may see a full HTML page without any error codes, like the main page of the site if the redirects are being done to suppress errors to end-users.

I'm also a little confused at the structure of your `$.ajax` call.  You may want to change it to the following:

```
function validateForm() {
    var form = $("#form1");
    $.ajax({
        /* context: form, //not sure you need that */
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'validate-attrib-form.php',
        data: form.serializeArray(), /* turn the form data into an array */
        dataType: "text",
        success: function(response){  
            alert(response);
            /* do other stuff... */
        }
    });
}

$("#form1").on("submit", function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    validateForm();
};
```

You don't need to specify a form `action` attribute if you are attempting to make an AJAX call to an endpoint.